# Server.methods and module

Tags: hapi.js

We are migrating from an architecture sharing code through server.methods to a more classic one based on modules.

Doing that, we are facing a new issue. We cannot easily access server.methods from modules and so, we cannot use the cache system attached to them.

How should I organize the code ? Should I export the server.methods object as a module at server start ? Should I export the server object and create server methods within modules ? Should I go deeper and create a plugin that handle server methods creation ?